# Show that f is continuous if graf(f) is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The graph of $f\colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a set $\{(x,y)\in M\times R \mid y=f(x)\}$. $M$ is a metric space and $\operatorname{graf}(f)$ is given by $\operatorname{graf}(f)=\{(x,y) \in  M \times \mathbb{R} \mid f(x)=y\}$.

Show that $f$ is continuous if $\operatorname{graf}(f)$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\operatorname{graf}(f)$ is compact. Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ be open and $x_0\in M$ with $f(x_0)\in U$. We have to show that for suitable $\epsilon>0$, we have $f(x)\in U$ for all $x\in M$ with $d(x,x_0)<\epsilon$. The open sets $V_n=\{\,(x,y)\in M\times\mathbb R\mid d(x,x_0)>\frac1n\,\}$ cover $\operatorname{graf}(f)$ except $(x_0,f(x_0))$. Together with $M\times U$ we have an open cover of  $\operatorname{graf}(f)$. From a finite subcover let $n$ be maximal with $V_n$ occuring in it. Then all $(x,y)$ with $d(x,x_0)<\epsilon:=\frac1n$ can only be covered by $M\times U$, i.e. $f(x)\in U$ for all $x$ with $d(x,x_0)<\epsilon$.